# Injecting javascript into zombie.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, zombie.js, headless-browser

Hi I was wondering if there is the ability in node js and zombie js to inject javascript files in to the headless browser, similar to what you can do with phantomjs.

For example in phantom js you would do:

```
page.injectJs("amino/TVI.js")
```

I have used phantomjs and it does do what I want it to do but however I am testing other options due to the high memory required by using phantom js.

Comment: Are you familiar with how bookmarklets work?  Maybe that could help you do what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

you can append script tag into document object since it support DOM API in zombie.

The following example shows how to insert jquery into zombie homepage:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");    

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://zombie.labnotes.org/", function () {    

  assert.ok(browser.success);

  // append script tag
  var injectedScript = browser.document.createElement("script");
  injectedScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  injectedScript.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");    

  browser.body.appendChild(injectedScript);    

  browser.wait(function(window) {
    // make sure the new script tag is inserted
    return window.document.querySelectorAll("script").length == 4;
  }, function() {
    // jquery is ready
    assert.equal(browser.evaluate("$.fn.jquery"), "1.11.0");
    console.log(browser.evaluate("$('title').text()"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to think the other way around. You have already everything at your hand in zombie to inject everything you want.

For example: `that.browser.window` points to the jsdom window that every part of your site javascript is using as a base. So you can access the dom and all other window objects in the page already loaded.

I don't know what you want to archieve with injecting - you should not use it for testing anway, but it looks this is not your actual goal