# How to run an external script in mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, zombie.js, external-script

This might be a silly question, but I've got to ask the community anyways.

I am using Zombie.js and Mocha for my test and I have an external script named:external.js.

```
// external.js

module.exports = "console.log('hey');";
```

I would like to load this external script into the mocha test (not Zombie.js's opened browser) and run it before running the test.

```
var myScript = require('../external.js');

describe('test script load', function() {
  browser.visit('www.example.com', done);

  // I want to load the external script here and run it before perfoming the test

  it('loads script', function (done) {
    browser.assert.success();
    done();
  });
});
```

I've tried several methods like creating a script tag and inserting my external script but seems to work when in HTML (because it works well in Zombie's browser) but I want the script before running the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like injecting a script into the page zombie.js is loading? See: [Injecting javascript into zombie.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989272/injecting-javascript-into-zombie-js).

If not that, you could try something like this:

external.js:

```
 function doSomething() {
    console.log('hi there!');
 } 

 module.exports = doSomething;
```

mocha.js:

```
 var doSomething = require('./external.js');

 your test....

 doSomething();

 your test continued...
```

That should work.

Comment: No, not injecting into zombie's page.
Injecting into mocha before or after zombie loads the page but definitely before running the test.

Comment: Okay, but you want to use function from another script in your test. If you put it in a function and then export that function and assign it to an import with the same name and then invoke it in your test script, it should work.

Comment: I gained some insight from your approach.

Yes, done that.

Comment: But the problem you're having is its not running **before** your test? I found an asynchronous solution I can post to you, but it might be overkill for what you need. Or does it work okay?

Comment: Post it anyways, It might turn out very useful another day

Comment: For waiting for asynchronous code in a mocha test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366730/run-async-code-before-entire-mocha-test

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out